# Angles sum in a triangle on the x- axis.

Tags: triangles

[image]
$\angle BCA=90$ degrees

I probably do not understand the concept of angle sum in a triangle but here is the thing. $\angle BAC$ is negative by convention.
So is $BCA$ going to be greater than 180 degrees?

So this is obviously wrong(or is it?). I suppose you should take only the magnitude of the angle into account. Can someone tell me when you should consider the sign and when you should not?

Comment: Angle BAC is only negative because of its "direction", not by its magnitude. When we looks at the sum of the angles in a triangle, when look at their magnitudes. The sum of the angles in any triangle (drawn on a flat surface) is equal to 180°

Comment: Just as a note, the convention only applies to angles that are made with the x-axis, so for example, you couldn't conclude anything  about $\angle ABC$ as to whether its positive or negative? So that convention shouldn't be used here. It is however useful for dealing with the unit circle for example.

Comment: @imranfat Maybe you misinterpreted what I said because I think that is what I guessed. Could you tell me why introducing negative angles proves useful?

Comment: Study the topic of inverses with respect to sine and tangent and it will become clear...

Comment: Every angel is defined actually as "angel"+nX360, n being an whole number - so, clockwise direction reduces the value of "angel" and by selecting n large enough any angel may be expressed as a negative angel, BAC